# GtkListStore adding (segmentation fault)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk, gtk3, glib

I am trying to pass a GSList to a GtkListStore to show to the user. But when i set the value to the GtkListStore, it just gives me segmentation fault. I really dont know where is the problem.
I tested the list, so it is not empty, and it have gchar vectors, as expected.

```
enum {
    COLUMN_FILENAME,
    NUM_COLUMNS
};

GtkBuilder *builder;

void add_to_source_list(gpointer filename, gpointer list_store) {
    GtkTreeIter iterator;
    gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(list_store), &iterator);

    // When the program reaches this line it gives segmentation fault
    gtk_list_store_set_value(list_store, &iterator, COLUMN_FILENAME, filename);
}

void source_files_list_update() {
    GSList *list = file_manager_get_all_sources();

    GtkListStore *list_store;
    list_store = gtk_list_store_new(NUM_COLUMNS,
                                G_TYPE_STRING);

    GtkTreeView *tree_view;
    tree_view = GTK_TREE_VIEW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, TREE_VIEW_ID));
    g_assert_true(tree_view != NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_set_model(tree_view, GTK_TREE_MODEL(list_store));

    GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

    GtkTreeViewColumn *column;
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("FILENAME", renderer, "text", COLUMN_FILENAME, NULL);

    gtk_tree_view_append_column(tree_view, column);
    g_slist_foreach(list, add_to_source_list, list_store);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`gtk_list_store_set_value()` takes a `GValue` as its last argument, not a string. You would normally get a compiler warning for situations like this, but in this case `filename` is still a `gpointer`, which is a `void *`, and thus the compiler assumes you were doing the right thing.

The easiest way to fix your program is to use `gtk_list_store_set()` instead. Read [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html) (and follow jcoppens's advice anyway, though I'm not sure if it would have helped in this case...).

Comment: I have already tried swithing to `gtk_list_store_set()` only putting a -1 (i guess it is a -1, or a NULL, i am not in my computer, so im not sure) as the last argument (after the filename), and it still gave me a segmentation fault.

Comment: andlabs is correct. You cannot pass the filename directly - you have to convert it first to a GValue! If you follow the backtrace after the segmentation fault, you'll see that the error is located in the GValue code. Make your life easier, and use `gtk_list_store_set()`, so you don't have to touch the GValues.

Comment: @HPerin are there no other warnings on stderr?

Comment: This is really strange... @HPerin Is `file_manager_get_all_sources()` one of your functions, and if so, could you post its source too?

Comment: @HPerin is your program still crashing? If so, can you post `file_manager_get_all_sources()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run the code in `gdb`. You didn't say which IDE (if any) you are using, but you may have to recompile the program with the `-g -O0` options to gcc:

```
gcc -g -O0 <old options>
```

(The `-O0` switches off any optimization, so following the code is simpler. `-g` includes debug info).

Then you can run the program in `gdb`, and, after the segmentation fault, do a 'backtrace' with the command `bt`. This will give you the exact function where the segfault occurred and make it easier to pinpoint the problem.

I'd also try adding a `printf("%s\n", filename);` just where you put the comment about the segfault. Then you can see when the segfault occurs (if there were successful passes or not)

Comment: I am using CLion, and it already has the debugger included, so thats how i concluded the error was in the line after the comment.